# Get a new preview on facebook.com

Tags: html, facebook, social-networking

the last website, I created, became a "coming soon" site before relaunch. Now it is available to the public. If i want to promote it on FB and type the URL in my status line, I always get the preview image and preview meta description from the preview website!

How I can force FB to load new information from the website. It seems to be that FB stores these informations. Maybe I only have to wait a little bit longer but maybe there is a easy solution?!

Thx
Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to wait. They're caching it all heavily. Maybe try to put your URL [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)  and it may refresh imediatelly. Otherwise, you'll have to wait

Comment: Thanks a lot! I put my URL in the FB debugger and it refreshed immediately!